# run a thread group after specific time

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am running one scenario for 2 hours in which I am using service which generates the cookie.. and that cookie is getting expired after 30 minutes. 
So I want to create a thread group which will run after 30 minutes so that new cookie will get replace with old cookies.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup another [thread group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) with a 30min startup delay.

[image]

Add a constant timer with 30min to ensure the delay after the first execution.

[image]

Best approach could be to check the expiry with a [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) and add the requests within the if controller.

Comment: Thank @Janesh. I want this threads to execute after 30 mins for 2 hours i.e. 4 threads. In that case how this will work?

Comment: Please seet the `Duration (seconds)`in the thread group as per the required duration. i.e 2hr*60*60=7200 (seconds). Set the delay you want to introduce between the iteration in the constant timer. Number of threads (4) can be set in the thread group.

Answer (score 0):

To make this simple

Create a thread group with number of threads as 1 with ramp up as 1 second.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Create a loop controller and add loop count as 4.
Create your request under this loop controller and also add constant timer as child of your request as shown below :

[image]
[image]

Execution flow will be:
First request will get executed . Once this first request gets a response from the server, it will wait for 30 mins. Then this loops again 4 times. You can control the number of execution in the loop count.

Answer (score 0):

The options are in:

1. Just specify "Startup delay" for the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group):

   [image]
2. Add Flow Control Action sampler as the first sampler in the Thread Group and configure it to pause for the half and hour:

   [image]
3. Use custom thread group like [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) (can be installed as a part of [Custom Thread Groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups) bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)) where you can precisely define when and how to start threads:

   [image]